# "Unable to read from monitor: connection reset by peer " error message when trying to open VM in RHEL6

Tags: linux, rhel, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

i need help to fix this problem,
When i trying to open VM on RHEL6 the error message appear "Unable to read from monitor: connection reset by peer " .